# What's the best practice to handle a large amount of audio files in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, avfoundation

Currently I am developing an iPhone application with a large amount of videos and audios. I implemented videos using HTTP Live Streaming which is working well. But For those audio files, I am thinking maybe do the streaming as well. But each of them is pretty small, and the total playback time is only 2-3 seconds. So I don't have to use HLS at all.
The problem is that for `AVAudioPlayer`, it only supports local files, but it seems silly to put those audio files to the bundle. I can synchronically download the file and pass the `NSData` pointer to `AVAudioPlayer`, but it's really hard to control the play loop if I want to play multiple audio files in sequence.
Hopefully you guys can help me figure this out or give me some hints. Thank you very much.

Comment: I would download the files to the cache directory, then create the AVAudioPlayer(s) for them from there. What difficulties are you running into?